# Using the Answer form of Answers module?

Tags: panels, 7

I am building a Drupal 7 site using: page manager, Panels, Views and the [Answer](https://drupal.org/project/answers) module.

In the [Answer module page](https://drupal.org/project/answers) and on the [Demo site](http://www.answers-demo.chipcleary.com/node/5) there is an option to put the Answer form in the same page with the question.

1. How can I do that on my site?
   I can find how to define that..
2. In addition, how can I do put the answer form on a Panel Page?

Please Note: This Question is different because it dealing with the specific version (7.x-4.0-alpha1) of the answer module. in this version the Answer form can be displayed in the question page. 
The other question I have asked has no relation to the answer module specifically, although I am trying over few days to achieve the same goal.
I already wrote that the answer I got is problematic, and did not solve the problem.

I will be very happy to get any help or suggestions, since I am dealing with this issue for few days without a solution!

Comment: Please stop editing your posts with single characters just to bump them up to the front page. Also, if you have more information to add to a question you've already asked, please edit the _original_ question. Don't ask it again with slightly different wording. Thanks

Comment: Please allow this question to be live again. It is not a duplicate, but a different way to achieve the same goal with a different modules or method. In the other question I already explained that the solution is not good and not stable..

Comment: Sorry, it's too close to the other one. If the approach from the duplicate doesn't work, then update the body of _that_ question to explain why, and that you're looking for different approaches. Whether a question is considered duplicate or not doesn't depend on the answers it might get, just the question itself.

Comment: Also, you really must stop deleting questions just so that you can ask them again and push them up to the top of the front page. I can see that you've done it at least 3 or 4 times now. If your question isn't getting the attention you think it should, then **improve the question** or offer a bounty. Don't delete it then ask it again to get around the rules - that sort of activity will not be received well. If you didn't know you weren't supposed to do that then no problem, let's just draw a line under it now that you _do_ know, and we'll go from here. Thanks